# What parameters can be tweaked to avoid a generator or discriminator loss collapsing to zero when training a DC-GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model

Sometimes when I am training a DC-GAN on an image dataset, similar to the DC-GAN PyTorch example (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html), either the Generator or Discriminator will get stuck in a large value while the other goes to zero. How should I interpret what is going on right after iteration 1500 in the example loss function image shown below [image: DC-GAN Training Loss]? Is this an example of mode collapse? Any recommendations for how to make the training more stable? I have tried reducing the learning rate of the Adam optimizer with varying degrees of success. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

GANs are notably hard to train and it is not uncommon to have large bumps in the losses. The learning rate is a good start but the instability may come from a wide variety of reasons. I'm assuming that you have no bug in your code or data.

For one, gradient descent is not well suited to the 2-player game we're playing. I've personally found ExtraAdam to yield much more stable training ([code](https://github.com/GauthierGidel/Variational-Inequality-GAN/blob/master/optim/extragradient.py), [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10551)).

It could also come from the loss and many tricks have been developed and one of the most popular one is enforcing smoothness in the gradient (see W-GAN, W-GAN-GP etc.). SpectralNorm ([code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/utils/spectral_norm.py) [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05957)) is a very popular and recent normalization technique for the discriminator.

There are a number of additional tricks to make GANs work like label smoothing and flipping, different update rates for the discriminator and generators (as in BigGAN for instance). I suggest you have a look at this nice repo of (somewhat seasoned) tricks: [ganhacks](https://github.com/soumith/ganhacks).